# How to add element into a nested array using json4s with Scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, json4s

I have the following json String:

```
  val jsonMessage: String =
    """{
      | "code": "OK",
      | "idEvent": "123",
      | "contract": {
      |     "idApplication": "001"
      | },
      | "version": {
      |     "idVersion": "1",
      |     "entity": [{
      |       "idEntity": "5",
      |       "entityType": [{
      |         "entityNumber": "147",
      |           "entityVersion": [{
      |             "entityCode": "A",
      |             "idCode": "753"
      |           }]
      |       }]
      |     }]
      | }
      |}""".stripMargin
```

I would like to position a new `name` field within the `entityVersion` array using `json4s`. Any idea how to do this in Scala ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code snippet:

```scala
val root = JsonMethods.parse(jsonMessage)
root.transformField {
  case ("entityVersion", JArray(list)) =>
    val updatedObjects = list.map { case obj: JObject =>
      JObject(obj.obj :+ ("name", JString("Name Value")))
    }
    ("entityVersion", JArray(updatedObjects))
}
```